# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Wordpress when uploading images or creating new post

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Environment: Apache / Linux 7.7 / PHP 7.2.10 / Wordpress

I am getting a net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error in Wordpress when I try to upload a new image or create a new post or page. When trying to create a new post, the error repeats in the console as wordpress tries to save the draft. I have found similar questions posted but most seem to point to browser issue.

- error ONLY occurs when I am using the domain
- error does not occur when I am using the machine name
- I have gone through multiple troubleshooting sessions with the firewall team, and they insist that the connection is getting reset at the server, not the firewall
- domain is SSL
- this happens in all browsers
- error occurs even with a fresh install of wordpress - no plugins
- we have a dev environment that IS working with the url, but test environment, which is supposed to be identical, is not working with url. The main difference in two environments is an additional firewall, but firewall team says there is nothing they can see on firewall that would cause this.

Here is the error:

```
POST https://[domain here]/wp-admin/async-upload.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,utils,moxiejs,plupload,plupload-handlers,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-tabs,jquery-form&ver=5.5.1:formatted:7172
```

Below is a sample virtual host entry. I think this is ok but posting in case someone might see an issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
     DocumentRoot /apache/httpd/www/html/]folder]
     ServerName [domain here]:443
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule .* - [E=REQUEST_SCHEME:https]
</VirtualHost>
```

Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Contact your web hosting company and ask them to increase your PHP memory limit.

- Or you can increase by adding the below code in the wp-config.php file

  define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
- Or you can also increase it by adding the below code in .htaccess file

  php_value memory_limit 256M
- Or you can also increase it by adding the below code in web server's php.ini file

  memory_limit = 256M

Comment: I already have the memory limit set to 256M, and I don't think that would explain why everything works just fine when using the server name. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have checked Apache's error_log and/or PHP-FPM log?
My `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` issue occurred because WordPress spammed a lot of PHP notices and PHP-FPM killed the process with

`FastCGI: too much stderr received from server /path-to-instance/php74-fpm", increase FCGI_SERVER_MAX_STDERR_LINE_LEN (1023) and rebuild or use "\\n" to terminate lines, referer: https://wordpress-instance/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php`

I've [fixed](https://www.schakko.de/2020/12/14/diagnosing-and-fixing-an-err_connection_reset-error-in-wordpress/) it by simply putting a

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`

into the `wp-config.php`. Maybe you have some customization in your `wp-config.php` which enables or disables logging, based upon your domain name?

Comment: This is not a solution, you are just muting the warning.